# Punching a web server through home router programmatically, automatically

Tags: networking, webserver, portforwarding

The premise is this;

We have a piece of hardware, bought by a consumer with no technical skill. This hardware runs a web server, hosting a simple web site. This web site needs to be reachable even if it's sitting behind a home router firewall. How could this be solved? The connection doesn't strictly have to go over port 80 to the web server, some forwarding could be in the equation too, if needed.

How would you solve this?

Comment: I would advise you rework your architecture. Note that some ISPs are going to frown on a home internet connection hosting any kind of server. Usually this is against the ToS, though most just overlook it.

Comment: In my case, this is not a problem. But good pointer!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that normally need to happen for a web server to be accessible from the internet:

```
Network firewall - allow traffic on port 80 or 443 to the server
Server firewall - Proper pin holes or turn it off.
Web server - Bind all IP/hostnames properly
```

You can control the server firewall and the web server, what you need to get around is the network firewall. One way I have seen this done is by creating a site to site VPN between the web server and your location. You then point your firewall to redirect the traffic over the VPN and the web server that is now accessible from the internet, but all traffic does go through you.

With out adding entries to your clients firewalls or giving the web server a public IP this is not possible.

Comment: Interesting. So, basically, for every web server I would need a VPN tunnel in order to make it accessible? I've seen a service named forward.hq.. seems to work along these lines!

Comment: @Phil Yes, but you might be able to do some redirect. So that the traffic only initially goes via your gateway then a client/server connection is established.

Comment: Can I use NAT to make the machine with the web server call my server who will then tell the client how to access? I still don't get how I get from the external ip to the internal..

Comment: @Phil The firewall will do the NAT, unless you have access to the firewall you can't change NAT settings. By keeping a site to site VPN tunnel the Web server would have an IP that is different from its' local or from its' internet IP. You would be able to talk to the web server over the VPN on the VPN interface IP. Then you would initiate some sort of redirect to use it's external IP. Take a look at STUN that is used in VoIP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN Doesn't require a VPN, but does require a server to facilitate the NAT punch through.